# SimpleInjector RegisterCollection suppress SuppressDiagnosticWarning DisposableTransientComponent

Tags: simple-injector

Is there a way of suppressing the DisposableTransientComponent warning when using RegisterCollection?  I've got the following code that registers all implementations:

```
container.RegisterCollection<IQueryRunner<Request, Response>>(
   new[] { typeof(IRetrieverInterface).Assembly }
);
```

(buried in the interface dependency chain is an IDisposable).  I haven't been able to find a way of suppressing the "disposable transient" message for the implementations.  The only thing I've found thus far is suppressing the message for each implementation (which sort of defeats the purpose of RegisterCollection):

```
        public static void SuppressDisposableTransientWarning<TService>(this Container container, string message)
        {
            var registration = container.GetRegistration(typeof(TService)).Registration;
            registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, message);
        }
```

```
const string disposableTransientDataContextMessage =
            "Injected data contexts are intended for use in Commands and Queries. " +
            "The data context should be disposed by the Command or Query's Dispose method. ";

container.SuppressDisposableTransientWarning<ImplementationType1>(disposableTransientDataContextMessage);
container.SuppressDisposableTransientWarning<ImplementationType2>(disposableTransientDataContextMessage);
// ...
container.SuppressDisposableTransientWarning<ImplementationTypeN>(disposableTransientDataContextMessage);
```

Comment: Why is IDisposable there in the first place? And do you have control over this? I.e. could you remove IDisposable?

Comment: Ric's question is valid. Ignoring the warning will not cause that instance to be disposed. Why not register it as `Scoped`?

Comment: Your `disposableTransientDataContextMessage` seems to imply that you want to let Commands and queries dispose their injected dependencies, while they are created by SimpleInjector. That is not the way it should work. Simple Injector shoudl be in charge of disposing the object it creates. You should make the IQueryRunners `Scoped`